# Find a vector tangent to a circle

Tags: math, vector, geometry

I need to move a point by vectors of fixed norm around a central circle.
So to do this, I need to calculate the circle tangent vector to apply to my point.

Here is a descriptive graph :
[image]

So I know p1 coordinates, circle radius and center, and the vector norm d. I need to find p2 (= finding the vector v orientation).

I put on the graph some ideas I got to find it : p1' is p1 projected on the circle. And t is the tangent vector to C in p1'.

That should be easy, but I'm too weak in maths to figure how to implement this. So I would like an idea of the implementation this (language agnostic is okay, javascript is cool).

Extra cool if you can also get me how to implement clockwise and counter clockwise movement with this.

Edit : Obtained this

```
let vx = cx - p1x,
    vy = cy - p1y,
    norm = Math.sqrt((vx * vx) + (vy * vy)),
    p2x = p1x - (vy * d / norm),
    p2y = p1y + (vx * d / norm);
```

But there is still a quirk : using this on time, the point is slowly getting away from the center of the circle, performing a spiral.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Obtain vector Center of circle - point P1. Let's call this vector
   v1.
2. Tangent vector 't' is perpendicular to v1. If v1=(vx, vy) then
   t=(-vy,vx) . Just swap values and a sign (I wrote -vy, it could also be -vx, but not both -vy,-vx).
3. Setting one direction or the order is just using t2= -t1= (vy, -vx), or (-vy, vx)

For movements you must use normalized (||v|| = 1) vectors.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Following your indications I obtained this :

```let vx = cx - p1x,
vy = cy - p1y,
norm = Math.sqrt((vx * vx) + (vy * vy)),
p2x = p1x + (vy * d / norm),
p2y = p1y + (vx * d / norm);```

But that still doesen't work. Value of p2 is not as expected. Is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: Okay I figured out that perpendicular vector is obtained not only by swaping values as you said but also by reversing one of the sign. I would be glad to accept your answer if you edit that.

Comment: By the way, is it normal that with the algorithm I added to my question, the point slowly get away from the center, performing a spiral ?

Comment: Yes, a spiral because P1 was closer to circle center than new P2. The shorter modulus of P1P2, the slower spiral out. If you want a circle instead of a spiral then tangent can't be used.